# Express delete MongoDB entry dynamically

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, methods, backend

I want to delete an entry in MongoDB based on the id variable. However, it does not work when it is a parameter I give to the method. I already checked the variable inside the method and it is the correct value. Then I thought, it is maybe because the variable is a String so i changed it to a Number but it still does not work. The code is as follows:

```
async function DeleteID (collectionName, threadIDString) {
  const uri = "mongodb://ADDRESS";

  const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  try {
    const threadIDNum = parseInt(threadIDString);
    await client.connect();
    const database = client.db("DB")
    const eventCollection = database.collection(collectionName)
    await eventCollection.updateOne({}, {$unset: {threadIDNum: 1}})
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Basically threadIDNum and threadIDStirng both do not work within unset but when I insert a value manually in that place the code works.

Answer (score 0):

While using unset to remove the data.

```
await eventCollection.updateOne(
                        { 
                            threadIDNum: 1  // filter condition to fetch a record
                        },
                        { 
                           $unset: { threadIDNum: 1 }  // field that you want to remove
                        }
               )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answerd.  it actually works with this syntax if it is a hard coded number instead of a variable containing the number.